# Is there a way to use GrowlApplicationBridge without NSClassFromString?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, xcode4.2, growl

I'm trying to build a basic cocoa app that uses Growl.

Every time I want to use `GrowlApplicationBridge` I have to use something like

```
Class GAB = NSClassFromString(@"GrowlApplicationBridge");
[GAB performSelector:@selector(setGrowlDelegate:) withObject:self];
```

I would like to be able to just use

```
[GrowlApplicationBridge setGrowlDelegate:self];
```

Here's the compiler error that I get when I try the behavior that I want:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GrowlApplicationBridge", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in StatusMenuAppDelegate.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you're importing `<Growl/Growl.h>` at the top of that file and linking the framework into your app, you should be able to use `[GrowlApplicationBridge setGrowlDelegate:self]` just fine.

Check the top of the file and make sure you're importing it, and check your target's “Link Libraries and Frameworks” build phase and make sure you're linking it.

Comment: @Cyrus: You need to do both of those things. If you don't copy it, your app will fail to launch, because your users won't have it. If you don't link it, copying it was for naught. You must copy it (so that it will be present on users' machines) and link to it (so that your app will actually use it).